# What sort of database-intensive applications can I make to learn NoSQL databases such as redis/mongo?

Tags: database, nosql

I wanna learn more about NoSQL databases by writing an application making heavy, heavy use of simple writes/reads.

Could anyone offer some ideas into possible web apps? I had in mind:

- url shortener
- canvas based game that tracks keyboard movements
- autocomplete lookup services
- chat powered by node.js, chat logging powered by nosql database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scrape the Internet

Answer (score 1):

Design a notification system (twitter, FB updates) or a blog with comment tracking. The first one is a really good use case for simple fast read/writes. Cheers!